# Move images from one server to s3 PHP Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm trying to write a script where I'm trying to move images from an old server to Amazon s3. Is it possible to do by downloading the image from an url?

```
$companies = Company::all();

$companies->each( function ($company) {

    //some method to download file
    $file = download($company->logo);

    //Store on s3
    $filename = $file->storeAs('images', uniqid('img_') . "." . $file->guessClientExtension(),'s3');

    //Get the new path
    $new_path = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);

    //save the new path to logo
    $company->logo = $new_path;

    //save the new path
    $company->save();
}
```

Comment: yeah, use curl/guzzle or write a script to move the images via ssh

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [Php League FileSystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem)

It has an integration for laravel and other framewoks such as zend, Cake etc

The library has an adapter for amazon S3 V2 and amazon s3 V3

Full documentation [here](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com)